# Restrict generic Java input to one of two types

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have two different classes, `Stack<E>` and `Queue<E>`, which have methods having the exact same names (`void add(E item)`, `E remove()`, `boolean isFull()` & `boolean isEmpty()`).

I'm looking to implement a generic class `Container<ContainerType>` where `ContainerType` may only be either  a `Stack` or a `Queue`.

I tried implementing this as below, but the syntax seems to be incorrect:

```
public class Container<ContainerType extends Stack & Queue> {}
```

I'm guessing that this is pretty common and that there would be a preexisting way to do this, but I'm not able to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to factor out the commonality between "Stack" and "Queue" and make them a base class (or interface) that both support.

Comment: @Pointy: Oh! Silly me. Thanks. Could you post it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though things *can* (and often do) get more complicated, in this case it looks like you need to factor out the common interface components of your "Stack" and "Queue" classes into either a common base class, or a mutually-supported interface. Then the generic signature would be pretty obvious I think.